# Firebase JavaScript SDK v8.4.0 release enables emulator mode for storage. How can developers use this?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Release notes for [Firebase JavaScript SDK v8.4.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js) say

> Added a storage().useEmulator() method to enable emulator mode for storage. This allows you to set a storage emulator host and port.

Running `firebase init emulators` with the most recent version of the Firebase CLI at this time (v9.10.0) does not give "storage" as one of the emulators that can be initialised. Does that mean that the Firebase storage emulator is not yet ready for developers to use?

Comment: **Notice :** They also released SDK 8.4.1 yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked about this on the pull request for this feature and was directed to this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3256) on the firebase-tools github.

In a nutshell the storage emulator is still in "preview" mode so it's necessary to run `firebase --open-sesame storageemulator` before running `firebase init emulators`.